# working with external data base in android programing with eclipse

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

i'm a beginner in java and android. now i want to work with external database (cancer.db).
i created "DataBaseHelper" class.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "myDBName";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   


public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
   // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
   // to you to create adapters for your views.}
```

then i use codes below in "on create" method to create or open database:

```
 private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/info.myprogram/databases/";
 private static String DB_NAME = "cancer.db";
 DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

} catch (IOException ioe) {

    throw new Error("Unable to create database");

}

try {

    myDbHelper.openDataBase();

}catch(SQLException sqle){

    throw sqle;

}
```

i use these codes to get query. my table name is "shb":

```
        SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cc= db.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM shb WHERE _id=1",null);
    cc.moveToFirst();
String sss=cc.getString(1);
```

now when i start debugging i get errors. what's the wrong code? whats my mistake? how should i get query?
and excuse me for my weak English, because it's not my mother tongue .

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: i don't know, no code is highlighted. but in tab methode.class is writed source not found!!

Comment: please show the logact output, we need to know where exactly the issue is..

Comment: is this what you want??
06-30 07:37:03.543: W/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-30 07:37:03.615: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{460f0070 info.hossein.AgeGofti/.Page1}

Answer (score -1):

First create a sqlite database and create table inside it, put it in assets folder of your app.use that database by using following code. please make changes in code for your datbaseName, tableName, fieldsName and path of database etc. i have also write the code of getting list of data by passing paerticuler value.

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_CARS = "Cars";
public static final String COL_ENAME = "ename";
public static final String COL_MODAL = "modal";
public static final String COL_ANAME = "aname";
public static final String COL_TYPES = "types";

private static final String TAG = "MSSS : DatabaseHelper";
// Your Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "4saleCars.sqlite";
// Your Your Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private final Context myContext;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
// The Android's default system path of your application database. DB_PATH =
// "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/"
private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/net.forsalemall.android/databases/";


public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    try {
        createDataBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "DatabaseHelper_constuctor createDataBase :"
                        + e.fillInStackTrace());
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// ***************************** My DB Handler Methods
// *****************************
/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 **/
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        // Database already exist
        openDataBase();

    } else {

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        myDataBase = getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error createDataBase().");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 **/
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/*
 * public boolean isDataBaseExist() { File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH +
 * DATABASE_NAME); return dbFile.exists(); }
 */

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transferring bytestream.
 **/
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    try {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copyDataBase().");
    }
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException, IOException {
    try {
        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        throw new Error("Error openDataBase().");
    }
}

// ***************************** My DML Methods
// *****************************

public List<String> getModalList(String aname, Context context) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(context.getResources().getString(R.string.all));
    Cursor cursor;
    String query;
    query = "SELECT modal FROM Cars WHERE aname =  '" + aname + "';";

    try {
        cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext())

                list.add(Utils.getDecodedString(cursor.getString(0)));
        }
        cursor.deactivate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getModalList Error : " + e.fillInStackTrace());
    }
    return list;
}
  }
```

use this **getModalList** in your activity just like below

```
MySQLiteHelper dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(
                AdvanceSearchActivity.this);
String aname = Utils.getEncodedString(catName);

car_modal = dbHelper.getModalList(aname,AdvanceSearchActivity.this);
```